# how to include html parts into all pages in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some static HTML parts I need to add to all my PHP files. Let's say **static.html** as below

```
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/default.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/inbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="scss/iconmind.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/spinners.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
```

then in my PHP files I am adding

```
<? 
    include("static.html");
?>
```

but on every php page I have other .css files I want to include as well. Let's say

```
<link href="css/loader.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

so my question is,  after I add my static head tag how can I add other parts at the end before my tag is closed ?

The result should be as below

```
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/default.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/inbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="scss/iconmind.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/spinners.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/loader.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Either don't close the `<head>` tag in static.html (close it later), or have that file actually be a PHP file (static.php) that includes _another_ file, say, dynamic.php, that has the files that could change.

Answer (score 2):

Don't close the head in your html document. I don't think it is the proper way but it is simple to do. You just need to think of closing it on every page that you put the include into.

It would go something like that :

For static.html

```
<head>
<title>Template</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/default.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/inbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="scss/iconmind.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/spinners.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After that in your main php file you should then add the css you want and close the head

It would look like that.

```
<link href="css/loader.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

Alternatively you could add it later with javascript. Try and look for the .append method and how you could use it on the head.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it directly, once the tag is closed is is kept closed

maybe you could replace `static.html` by this `helper.php`

```php
<?php

function createHead($addons) {
?>

<head>
    <title>Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/default.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/inbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="scss/iconmind.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/spinners.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<?php
    echo $addons;
?>

</head>

<?php
}
```

then in your files you call :

```php
<?php
    include("helper.php");
    createHead('<link href="css/loader.css" rel="stylesheet">');
?>
```

using this way you could also add other arguments to the function such as the title